# Getting captcha invalid in Yii

Tags: php, yii

this is my model:
 */

```
class Contact extends BaseContact
{    
    public $verifyCode
.....
        public function rules()
    {
        return array(
        .......
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha', 'message'=>'Captcha invalid!') 
        );
    }
...
```

this is my controller:

```
if(!$model->validate()){
.....
}else{
if($model->save(false)){
}
```

and this is my view:

```
$this->widget('CCaptcha', 
                    array(
                            'captchaAction' =>'site/captcha',
                            'buttonOptions' => array('class'=>'test','style' => 'display:block'),
                            'buttonLabel'   => 'Schimbă codul'
                         )
              );
```

The fact is that it is always **model->validate()** is false . Why ?

Comment: something is wrong with this part if I commented this : array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha', 'message'=>'Captcha invalid!')  it works. but it means no captcha

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()` in your validation rule:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha', 'message'=>'Captcha invalid!', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements());
```

I'm not sure, but I think this can solve your problem.